# BlackBerry - Uncaught exception: Application(353) is not responding; process terminated

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app for BlackBerry OS 6.0 and onward. When I launch the app it gives an error:

> Uncaught exception: Application Trace(353) is not responding; process
>   terminated.

The exception is not thrown always but only at times.

Can anyone help resolve this error?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Debugging can help highlight where the error is. If the exception is thrown at times and not always, it could be due to simulator. The simulator might be crashing. Try "Clean Simulator" to remove all .dmp files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. when I am debug my app it is running smoothly. I am using GPS in my app, is this error depends on any kind of GPS issue? And i am running app in device 9900(BOLD)..

Comment: You might not be releasing a thread properly that is bringing about this error. Please see my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you get this error occasionally indicates you might be using an event thread for too long. In your case, you might be fetching GPS location updates at a continuous level in a thread.

When this issue occurs, the OS will force a stack trace dump for all running applications. You need to recover the event log and locate the stack trace for your application. This will help identify the lines of code that is hogging the processor.

Once you identify the offending code, you either need to modify it so that the event thread is not being monopolized, or possibly isolate the procedure in it's own thread so that the event thread can return to the system dispatcher.